# How do I mock a third party package with Jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocking, jestjs, enzyme

I want to be able to test whether or not this `Swal()` function is called.

It's mocked but I'm not familiar with the Jest mocking library.

This is in my test set up file:

```
jest.mock('sweetalert2', () => {
  return {
    Swal: () => {},
  };
});
```

So I just want this to return a function.

In my component, Swal is called like this:

```
doSomething = () => {
  Swal({
    title: 'Could not log in',
    text: error.message,
    type: 'error',
  });
};
```

I think my mock needs to return a named method, so I can spyOn it and check that it was called.

My test:

```
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';

describe('Login Container', () => {
  it('calls Swal', () => {
    doSomething();
    var swalSpy = jest.spyOn(Swal, 'Swal');
    expect(swalSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Error:

```
expect(jest.fn()).tohavebeencalled();
```

How should I set up my mock and spy as the test fails

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that the mock factory needs to return an object with `default` (because import Swal is importing the default module).  Something like this (demoing sweetalert v1):

```js
// extract mocked function
const mockAlert = jest.fn()

// export mocked function as default module
jest.mock('sweetalert', () => ({
  default: mockAlert,
}))

// import the module that you are testing AFTER mocking
import doSomethingThatAlerts from './doSomethingThatAlerts'

// test suite loosely copied from OP
describe('Login Container', () => {
  it('calls Swal', () => {
    doSomethingThatAlerts();

    // test mocked function here
    expect(mockAlert).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```